# Pass variable down to dependency helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart with an optional component.  It seems that the preferred way to support optional components is to break them into separate charts and toggle them with tags.

I tried this, but my optional component needs to know a variable from the rest of the chart (the address of a particular service).  This causes things to break

```
Error: render error in "subchart/foo-deployment.yaml": 
template: superchart/templates/_helpers.tpl:14:40: 
executing "superchart.variable <.Values.variable...>: 
can't evaluate field name in type interface {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this at install time for the chart

> helm install --set option1=value1 --name my-release stable/dask

For more info:
https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-install

Issue:
https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/944

PR:
https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/pull/982

Comment: In my case the variable I want to pass is the address of one of the other containers, and so is constructed from the auto-generated name of the deployment.  It's value looks something like `happy-panda-scheduler:8786`